# Swift - Passing data from model to controller using delegate design pattern

Tags: swift, model, controller, delegates, swift-protocols

i am a swift learner, and need assistance in passing data

Here i have ViewController and CoinManager model. What i am trying to do is call didUpdatePrice method that's declared inside my ViewController from CoinManager, this function is responsible to update the UI. I have implemented CoinManagerDelegate protocol in ViewController, but every time i am trying to call didUpdatePrice method it throws an error like this:

> Type '(any CoinManagerDelegate)?' has no member 'didUpdatePrice'

When i tried to declare delegate in my ViewController like this:

```
coinManager.delegate = self
```

it also returns an error like this:

> Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type '(any
> CoinManagerDelegate)?.Type'

Here's my ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, CoinManagerDelegate {
   
    var coinManager = CoinManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        coinManager.delegate = self
        currencyPicker.dataSource = self
        currencyPicker.delegate = self
    }
 
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return coinManager.currencyArray.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return coinManager.currencyArray[row]
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let selectedCurrency = coinManager.currencyArray[row]
        coinManager.getCoinPrice(for: selectedCurrency)
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var currencyPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var currencyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bitcoinLabel: UILabel!
    
    func didUpdatePrice(price: String, currency: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.bitcoinLabel.text = price
            self.currencyLabel.text = currency
        }
    }
    
}
```

And here's my CoinManager model code:

```
import Foundation

protocol CoinManagerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didUpdatePrice(price: String, currency: String)
}

struct CoinManager {
    var delegate = CoinManagerDelegate?.self
    
    let baseURL = "https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/BTC"
    let apiKey = "#API_KEY"
    
    let currencyArray = ["AUD", "BRL","CAD","CNY","EUR","GBP","HKD","IDR","ILS","INR","JPY","MXN","NOK","NZD","PLN","RON","RUB","SEK","SGD","USD","ZAR"]
    
    func getCoinPrice(for currency: String){
        let urlString = "\(baseURL)/\(currency)?apikey=\(apiKey)"
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    let data = parseJSON(safeData)
                    let dataString = String(format: "%.2f", data!)
                    self.delegate.didUpdatePrice(price: dataString, currency: currency)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ data: Data) -> Double? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(CoinData.self, from: data)
            let lastPrice = decodedData.rate
            
            return lastPrice
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!
On the internet, this method should works fine. But it didn't work on my machine.
I've tried to surf the internet and implemented their answers, but it didn't help me, i tried to ask chatGPT as well but the result is nil TwT. Thanks a lot fellow coders!

Comment: I think it should be ```coinManager.delegate = self``` not ```coinManager.delegate = ViewController```

Comment: @udi, thanks for commenting! i tried `coinManager.delegate = self` before, but it returns the same error, that's why i changed it to `coinManager.delegate = ViewController` just to trying stuffs out

Comment: Do you understand the delegate pattern? `coinManager.delegate = ViewController` doesn’t make any sense, you need to use `self` as suggested. `var delegate = CoinManagerDelegate?.self`, this doesn’t make sense either and is probably the root of the problem. Declare the property correctly and your code should work better.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson hi! thanks for commenting, as i explained before to udi, i changed it to `coinManager.delegate = ViewController` because i just wanted to try out (i'll change this soon to reduce confusion). As for the `var delegate = CoinManagerDelegate?.self`, i added the `.self` because swift recommends me. It throws an error when i type `var delegate = CoinManagerDelegate?`

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a type and an object and when to use each otherwise you will face a lot of difficulties when working with swift programming. When declaring a property to be of a specific type you use : and when you give a property an initial value you use =.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the following in your code this should work at your end
in `ViewController`  change `coinManager.delegate = ViewController` to `coinManager.delegate = self`
and in `CoinManager`  update the following

```
var delegate = CoinManagerDelegate?.self
```

to

`var delegate : CoinManagerDelegate?`

on call back with delegate first make sure delegate connection is successfully connect

```
if let del = self.delegate
{
     del.didUpdatePrice(price: dataString, currency: currency)
}
```